# How to find, geometrically, the minimum distance from one arc of an ellipse to a line?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Here's a problem statement:

**Find the minimum distance between a point $P(x,y)$ on the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{9} = 1$ with $x,y\ge0$ and the line $x-y-5=0$.**

It is clear that the line is a tangent to the ellipse because if we solve the line and ellipse we get equal roots. But the point of contact lies in the fourth quadrant. Therefore there is no common normal in the given arc of the ellipse and the line. So the method of finding the minimum distance between the ellipse and line with the help of common normal won't work here.

I took a point $(4|\cos\theta|, 3|\sin\theta|)$ on the ellipse. And I simply calculated the distance to the line, that is
$$
d = \frac{|4|\cos\theta| - 3|\sin\theta| -5|}{\sqrt2}.
$$
It is easy to show that $4|\cos\theta| - 3|\sin\theta|\in[-3, 4]$. So the minimum value of $d$ is $\boxed{\dfrac1{\sqrt2}}$.

**My question:** Is there any way to this geometrically without help of coordinates or trigonometry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ellipse is centered in origin $(0,0),$ its semin-major and semi-minor axis are $4$ and $3,$ respectively.
The line cuts the coordinate axes in points $(0,-5),(5,0).$
The ellipse is located above the line.

[image]

The point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse with $x,y\ge0$ and closest to the line is the vertex $A(4,0).$

Comment: Please give justification.

Comment: You have a differentiable function (signed distance to line) -- let's call it $f$ --  defined on the plane. Consider $c:[0, \pi/2] \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $c(t) = (5 \cos t, 3\sin t$, which parameterizes the arc. Let $g(t) = f(c(t))$. Then $g$ is a real-valued function on an interval; its extrema lie either where $g'(t) = 0$ or at the endpoints. Now $g'(t) = f'(c(t)) \cdot c'(t)$; $f'$ is a constant vector to the northwest, more or less, while $c'(t)$ points somewhere between east and south, hence is never orthogonal to $f'$. So $g'$ is never $0$, so the min and max happen at the endpoints.

Comment: @prashantsharma The arc of ellipse is all inside a rectangle (0,0)-(4,0)-(4,3)-(0,3). Which is the point of that rectangle nearest to the given line?

Comment: @JohnHughes I am looking for non-calculus, non-trig approach.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca How are you convincing yourself, it is (4, 0)?

Comment: @prashantsharma Consider the line $b$ passing through $(4,0)$ and parallel to the given line $a$: the rectangle all lies on one side of $b$, while $a$ lies on the opposite side. Hence any other point of the rectangle has a distance from $a$ greater than the distance of $(4,0)$.

Comment: @prashantsharma imagine that the line moves to the left, keeping the direction. Between all these parallel  lines, the first one that cuts the ellipse in a point in the first quadrant, is $x-y-4=0.$ Its common point with the ellipse is the vertex $(4,0).$

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that any parameterization of the arc will give you the same result as $c$ does, i.e., the use of trig in my answer was just for simplicity. You could have used $e(t) = (\sqrt{16 - \left(\frac{4y}{3}\right)^2}, t)$ equally well. All that matters is that the tangent is never orthogonal to the (roughly) NW direction. As for "non-calculus"...well, you might have mentioned that at the start. I thought you merely wanted to avoid Lagrange multipliers ("no common normal"), which give no useful info (as you observed) in this case. Sigh.